# Border not transparent with linear gradient

Tags: html, css, border, transparent, linear-gradients

Why when I apply transparent border to div with linear-gradient, border is not transparent on top and bottom.

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(pink, red);
  border: 20px solid transparent;
```

}

screenshot
http://i43.tinypic.com/2r3gjmx.png

Comment: I didn't understand what you trying to say.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to use some thing like this

```
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(pink, red);
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. it works. But why transparent border displays incorrect? It is a bug?

Comment: for transparent border you have to use RGB code like rgba(0,0,0,0.3)

Comment: 0.3 is the amount of transparency

Comment: it is much easier. with "no-repeat" it's look fine

Answer (score 15):

For anybody who's looking for a solution:

**TLDR**

```
background-origin: border-box;
```

**Explanation** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin

Comment: Maybe you could extend your answer with a bit more context why this a solution and how it works (at best with a snippet example)?

Comment: Make sure to add `background-origin` after the  `background` css property, otherwise it will have no effect.

Answer (score 7):

@dimann90 has the correct solution in the comments. Use `background-repeat: no-repeat` on the element.

Here's why this works:

A background image repeats infinitely in the x and y directions by default. A linear-gradient is a background image, and the size of that image is controlled by the size of the content box (it's actually [more complicated](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#gradient-box), but this is good enough for our purposes). An element's background extends through the padding and border (but not margin). So, a border will cause the total size of the element's box to be bigger than the generated background image, and it will repeat. If the border is transparent, then the repeating image will show through.

Comment: This sort of solves the problem, but for some reason anti-aliasing is lost in Chrome on OSX when setting `no-repeat`. Also, the reason I'm personally using a transparent border is so that the element has the same dimensions as an element _with_ a border (I have two buttons side by side - one with a gradient bg, one with a transparent bg and border). When setting `no-repeat` that no longer works (the transparent button with border is now its `border-width` larger than the other)